# How to set comments for 3 cells using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to set comments for 3 excel cells using Apache POI.

This is my source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

public class CellComments
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

      HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
      HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Cell comments in POI HSSF");


      HSSFPatriarch patr = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      HSSFCell cell1 = sheet.createRow(3).createCell((short)1);
      cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Hello, World"));

      //anchor defines size and position of the comment in worksheet
      HSSFComment comment1 = patr.createComment(new HSSFClientAnchor(100, 100, 100, 100, (short)1, 1, (short) 6, 5));
      comment1.setString(new HSSFRichTextString("FirstComments"));
      cell1.setCellComment(comment1);
      System.out.println("Cell comments: "+cell1.getCellComment().getString());

      patr = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      comment1 = patr.createComment(new HSSFClientAnchor(100, 100, 100, 100, (short)1, 1, (short) 6, 5));
      //HSSFComment comment2=patr.createComment(new HSSFClientAnchor(100, 100, 100, 100, (short)1, 1, (short) 6, 5));
      HSSFCell cell2 = sheet.createRow(6).createCell((short)1);
      cell2.setCellValue(36.6);
      comment1.setString(new HSSFRichTextString("second commetns"));
      cell2.setCellComment(comment1);
      System.out.println("Cell comments: "+cell2.getCellComment().getString());

      patr = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      comment1 = patr.createComment(new HSSFClientAnchor(100, 100, 100, 100, (short)1, 1, (short) 6, 5));
      //HSSFComment comment3=patr.createComment(new HSSFClientAnchor(100, 100, 100, 100, (short)1, 1, (short) 6, 5));
      cell2 = sheet.createRow(10).createCell((short)1);
      cell2.setCellValue(150);
      comment1.setString(new HSSFRichTextString("Third commetns"));
      cell2.setCellComment(comment1);
      System.out.println("Cell comments: "+cell2.getCellComment().getString());

      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/saravanan/Desktop/cellcomments.xls");
      wb.write(out);
      out.close();

    }
}
```

While run the program, comments set only for last cell. But I printed the comments for the first two cells it was printed fine. But not shown in the excel sheet? What's incorrect here?

Comment: Great question!!  Taught me how to write comments with NPOI.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For once you've asked a question which had me trying out the code for a while.

Your problem is this line appears 3 times, once before each comment.

```
patr = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
```

From [the docs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#createDrawingPatriarch%28%29) for this method,

> Creates the top-level drawing
>   patriarch. This will have the effect
>   of removing any existing drawings on
>   this sheet.

So whats happening is that your earlier comments are getting removed each time you create the DrawingPatriarch.

So do this only once, before `comment1`. The other 2 times, remove or comment out this line.

Comment: @Saravanan: no private tuitions on offer here. Ask a proper question, you will get a reply from the community. See this URL for how to ask good questions. www.tinyurl.com/so-hints